# chmod(): Operation not permitted when upload file with laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, file

I am using [file system storage](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem) to upload files. When I change filesystem_driver from local to public I get this error :

> vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php:367

```
public function setVisibility($path, $visibility){
    $location = $this->applyPathPrefix($path);
    $type = is_dir($location) ? 'dir' : 'file';
    $success = chmod($location, $this->permissionMap[$type][$visibility]); // line 367

    if ($success === false) {
        return false;
    }
```

*Disk settings*

```php
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

I tried to change the file permissions according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel), but it doesn't work. If I change the `filesystem_driver` to local I cannot display the pictures in front end. This is a local development environment **WSL Ubuntu 18**.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: storage directory has wrong permissions it should be apache or nginx as owner of the directory  via `sudo chown www-data:www-data storage`

Comment: @Bader I did that but it doesn't help. files being uploaded but this error comes up regardless after posting the form.

Comment: did you linked your public folder with `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @bader it turns out windows subsystem linux does not support cmod if your webfiles are outside of linux. I moved files into linux file system and it's working now. only problem I have is that I cannot display the pictures now.

Answer (score 2):

problem was cmod is not support under ntfs file system https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81